# Add the ability for job posters to identify the salary period

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Not all countries list their salaries on a yearly basis, sometimes the salary is monthly (or bi-weekly).

Therefore, I would suggest adding the ability to have employers select the period and this be displayed along with the salary.